# Running IE using selenium webdriver

Tags: eclipse, selenium, firefox

I would appreciate if someone could help with the code below

package IEProjects;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

```
public class startIE {



          public static void main(String[] args) {

                System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\IEDriverServer_Win32_3.3.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
                WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();              
                driver.get("http://www.google.com");

            }

        }
```

And am getting the below results

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
3.3.0.0
Listening on port 29209
Only local connections are allowed
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Browser zoom level was set to 150%. It should be set to 100% (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

It launches IE and didnt perform the action. Below is what is printed on the IE page

```
This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server. http://localhost:41380/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is descriptive enough, there is a set of pre-requisites to the IEDriver:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration

Notice:

- The browser zoom level must be set to 100% so that the native mouse events can be set to the correct coordinates.